# How To Parse an Array of Numbers in Typescript/NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am writing a simple calculator that takes two arguments.

The first is an array of numbers (one number of hours for x amount of days)

The second is a single number (the target number of hours)

The app calculates the average of the first array and checks whether that average is higher than the target specified (the second number)

I am trying to parse the first Array of numbers, unfortunately Node JS does not seem to recognise the array: [2, 2, 3, 2] as a single argument - it recognises the first value of the array ("2") as the first argument, and the second ("2") as the second argument and so on.

```
 const a = Array(args[2]).map(h => Number(h))
```

This is the specific line of code where I am trying to parse an array.

How do you Parse the two arguments so that NodeJS recognises the entire array [2, 2, 3, 2] as a single argument?

Here is the code:

```
    interface exerciseResult {
    periodLength: number;
    trainingDays: number;
    success: boolean;
    rating: number;
    ratingDescription: string;
    target: number;
    averageTime: number
}

interface arguments {
    a: number[]
    b: number
}

const parseArguments = (args: Array<string>): arguments => {
    if (args.length < 4) throw new Error('Not enough arguments');

    const a = Array(args[2]).map(h => Number(h))
    const b = Number(args[3])

    return { a, b}

  
}

const exerciseCalculator = (a: number[], b: number ): exerciseResult => {

    const periodLength = a.length
    const trainingDays = a.filter(a => a > 0).length
    const averageTime = a.reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0 ) / a.length 
    const success = averageTime > 2 ? true : false 
    const rating = averageTime > 3 ? 3 : averageTime > 2 && averageTime < 3 ? 2 : 1
    const ratingDescription = averageTime > 3 ? "good" : averageTime > 2 && averageTime < 3 ? "average" : "bad"
    const target = b

return {
    periodLength: periodLength,
    trainingDays: trainingDays,
    success: success,
    rating: rating,
    ratingDescription: ratingDescription,
    target: target,
    averageTime: averageTime
}
}

try {
    const { a, b } = parseArguments(process.argv);
    console.log(exerciseCalculator(a, b));
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    let errorMessage = 'Something bad happened.'
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      errorMessage += ' Error: ' + error.message;
    }
    console.log(errorMessage);
  }
```

THe code is run using the command exerciseCalculator([2, 2, 3, 2], 4)

Comment: can share "process.argv" data?

Comment: 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\node_modules\\ts-node\\dist\\bin.js',
  'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\Web Development\\bmiCalculator\\exerciseCalculator.ts',
  '[2',
  '3',
  '2',
  '2]',
  '4'

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your `process.argv` data.
`[2', '3', '2', '2]`, this cannot be taken as a single argument it should be as `[2, 3, 2, 2]`. And then update your `parseArguments` method as below:

```
const parseArguments = (args: Array<string>): arguments => {
    if (args.length < 4) throw new Error('Not enough arguments');
    const a = (JSON.parse(args[2])).map((h: any): number => Number(h))
    const b = Number(args[3])
    console.log(a)
    return { a, b}
}
```

Comment: `h: any` -> `h: unknown`